# validating input value but unable to try & except for other inputs too

Tags: python, validation, try-catch

i am trying to validate every input value but stuck here where if user put wrong value then my function stop taking other input & ask him to correct the error.

```
import re
import os.path
from csv import DictWriter
service ={}    

class App:
  def __init__(self):
    pass

  def services(self):
```

**Problem is here**

```
name=input("Enter Name: ")
name_r = re.match('^[a-zA-Z]{3,20}$',name)
if name_r:
  print("true")
else:
  print("Wrong Value Entered. Please Enter Correct Name")
```

i wanna use try & except block but exactly don't know how to use in this case.
if i put validated value in except block then rest of the input will also have have their own except block (am confused guide me) also the main problem, is there any short way to do this because if i validate each line like this so it will take so much time.

```
phone=input("Enter PTCL: ")
email=input("Enter Email: ")
mobile=input("Enter Mobile: ")
address=input("Enter Address: ")
service_type=input("Enter Problem Type: ")
date_time=input("Enter Date & Time: ")
msg=input("Enter Message: ")
```

Below Code is fine

```
    #getting input values
    service['name'] = name_r
    service['ptcl'] = phone
    service['mobile'] = mobile
    service['date_time'] = date_time
    service['service_type'] = service_type
    service['address'] = address
    service['msg'] = msg
    service['email'] = email

    file_exists = os.path.isfile(r"sevices.csv")
    with open(r"sevices.csv",'a',newline='') as for_write:
      writing_data = DictWriter(for_write,delimiter=',',fieldnames=["Name","Email","PTCL","Mobile","Service Type","Date & Time","Address","Message"])
      if not file_exists:
        writing_data.writeheader()

      writing_data.writerow({
        'Name': service['name'],
        'Email':service['email'],
        'PTCL':service['ptcl'],
        'Mobile':service['mobile'],
        'Service Type':service['service_type'],
        'Date & Time':service['date_time'],
        'Address':service['address'],
        'Message':service['msg']
        })

o1= App()
o1.services()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to accomplish what you want is to create a while loop that exits on an accepted input.

```
while True:
    name=input("Enter Name: ")
    name_r = re.match('^[a-zA-Z]{3,20}$',name)
    if name_r:
        break
    else:
        print("Wrong Value Entered. Please Enter Correct Name")
```

Comment: i have multiple inputs value, so how i pass all? my main problem is this

Comment: Each variable probably has its own regular expression and input text etc.. Easiest is to make one block for each input.